# Updating a table row with OleDB from C#

Tags: c#

I am working on an invoice managament application that draws information from an Access database (modern .accdb format) and getting the data works fine, but when I try to update it (following some tutorials, or should I say answers, nothing works.. 
What is wrong with this code, it... should work.

```
    public int UpdateDBBill(Bill bill)
    {
        using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\BC.accdb"))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();

            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE Bills SET Payer = @Payer, Category = @Category, Recipient = @Recipient, Currency = @Currency, Amount = @Amount, IBANOfRecipient = @IBANOfRecipient, Model = @Model, ReferenceNumber = @ReferenceNumber, Description = @Description, DueDate = @DueDate, ForMonth = @ForMonth, Paid = @Paid, DatePaid = @DatePaid WHERE Id = @Id";

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payer", bill.Payer);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", bill.Category);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Recipient", bill.Recipient);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Currency", bill.Currency);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", bill.amount);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IBANOfRecipient", bill.IBANOfRecipient);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", bill.Model);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReferenceNumber", bill.ReferenceNumber);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", bill.Description);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DueDate", bill.DueDate);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ForMonth", bill.ForMonth);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paid", bill.Paid);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatePaid", bill.DatePaid);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", bill.Id);

            try
            {
                return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                return -1;//for error
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer:

```
    public int UpdateDBBill(Bill bill)
    {
        using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\BC.accdb"))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();

            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            command.CommandText = "UPDATE Bills SET Payer = @Payer, Category = @Category, Recipient = @Recipient, [Currency] = @Currency, Amount = @Amount, IBANOfRecipient = @IBANOfRecipient, [Model] = @Model, ReferenceNumber = @ReferenceNumber, DueDate = @DueDate, ForMonth = @ForMonth, Paid = @Paid, DatePaid = @DatePaid WHERE Id = @Id";
            command.Parameters.Add("@Payer", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = bill.Payer;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Category", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = bill.Category;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Recipient", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = bill.Recipient;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Currency", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = bill.Currency;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Amount", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = bill.GetAmount();
            command.Parameters.Add("@IBANOfRecipient", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = bill.IBANOfRecipient;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Model", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = bill.Model;
            command.Parameters.Add("@ReferenceNumber", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = bill.ReferenceNumber;
            command.Parameters.Add("@DueDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = bill.DueDate.Date;
            command.Parameters.Add("@ForMonth", OleDbType.Date).Value = bill.ForMonth.Date;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Paid", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = bill.Paid;
            command.Parameters.Add("@DatePaid", OleDbType.Date).Value = bill.DatePaid.Date;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = bill.Id;

            try
            {
                int Rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return Rows;
            }
            catch
            {
                return -1;//for error
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With OleDb the position of the parameters matters a lot.
OleDb doesn't associate parameters' placeholders with the parameters' names but follows a strictly positional order. So, your query is correct, but when you add the parameters to the collection you should follow the parameter placeholders order.

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = "UPDATE Bills SET ([Payer] = @Payer, [Category] = @Category, ...) WHERE Id = @Id";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payer", bill.Payer);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", bill.Category);
....
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", bill.Id);
```

With Access you can name your parameters as you do for its big cousin Sql Server albeit the OleDb docs say that you should use the question mark as parameter placeholder, however the names are simply ignored when the OleDb provider associates the values to the placeholders.

As a side note, consider that AddWithValue is an handy but dangerous method. The parameter type is extracted by the value passed and sometimes this could create a 'DataType mismatch Exception' or wrong conversions (in particular if you pass dates or decimals as strings to AddWithValue)

See [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

**EDIT**  After a long debug session in chat the final problem is identified in the Currency field written withot brackets. Currency is a reserved words in Access and should be enclosed in square bracket. This was not initially evident because the first query proposed by the OP was correctly typed with square bracket but then the square brackets disappeared from the query for whatever reason. The suggestion to NOT use AddWithValue stands to avoid unnecessary conversions from dates to strings and then back to strings....

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE Bills SET ([Payer] = @Payer, [Category] = @Category, ...) WHERE Id = @Id";
command.Parameters.Add("@Payer", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = bill.Payer;
command.Parameters.Add("@Category", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = bill.Category;
....
command.Parameters.Add("@DueDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = bill.DueDate.Date;
....
command.Parameters.Add("@Id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = bill.Id;
```

Comment: I've tried that before and it didn't work. then I changed to how my code is now which didn't work either. After your answer, I've tried putting Id to the end again, but I still get an syntax with SQL statement error

Comment: Then it is better that you show the whole command text and the whole list of parameters. It is impossible to say what the syntax error is from this snippet.

Comment: I shortened the query simply because it repeats itself, and based from my previous MVC experience, you could say the class is indeed a model of the DB table with matching data types. I will make the edit in couple of seconds.

Comment: and regarding your side note, I wouldn't have issues using other methods, I just don't know them yet since before this I didn't work with OleDB at all.

Comment: The code seems to be correct, as I have said, I would only change the AddWithValue for _command.Parameters.Add("@Id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = bill.Id;_ and the same for the other parameters paying particular attention to the datatype expected by the table and the datatype of the properties of your Bill class. Still a single line, but no space database automatic conversion from the parameters values

Comment: is the order just as relevant?

Comment: Yes absolutely, that depends by OleDb not by Add

Comment: Another thing to check. When you add the parameters for date fields use: _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DueDate", bill.DueDate.Date);_ to clip away the time part (or use the Add method specifying a OleDbType.Date)

Comment: Wait, so Date/Time in access is not equal to DateTime? Because for some things I'd prefer it in a DateTime format, not JUST Date. This could be the core issue then!

Comment: The problem are the milliseconds part of a DateTime variable that are not well understood

Comment: I understand. However using .Date did not fix the issue. Syntax error stays.

Comment: Also command.Parameters.Add("@Id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = bill.Id; didn't work either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116262/discussion-between-steve-and-dethorhyne).

Answer (score 1):

I came across with this before. My issue was, I was not providing the parameters in the order they were present in the query.

In your case, as your update goes on with parameters Payer, Category...,Id  your AddWithValues should follow the same order.

I hope this helps

Comment: They are in the exact order. except the Id which in db AND the parameters is first, but in query it's mentioned last since it's in WHERE section

Comment: That is my point... You should not follow the order in the table but the order in your query. When i check, AddWithValue for Id field comes the first, instead, it should come the last

Comment: Understood, but as I commented above just now, that gives me the same error

Comment: Can you share the full sql? I will also check with the brackets. Maybe they are the issue...

Comment: Can you get rid of the parenthesis and try?

Comment: What about without parenthesis? In UPDATE statement specification, there is no usage like UPDATE table SET ( a=b, c=d )

Comment: Oh... but alas, same error without grouping the parameters

Comment: I am determined to find the issue here :) Can you share the structure of your table and provide a sample data for me? Also, wihch version of Access are you using? And... details of the class Bill would help me a lot

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bnvymr this is the database I'm using Access 2013. http://prntscr.com/bnvzb3 and here's the class

Comment: As far as the sample data.. some things here are personal, but you can use anything. As far as Date related items, they should be self explanatory.. due date could be 15.07.2016 but ForMonth should be first day in the (same) month.

Comment: You don't have any issues with populating Bill class from datarow right ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok... I found the issue.

First of all, you should put the Currency field in brackets because Access considers it as a datatype if you don't and you get Syntax error.

Then, keep all AddWithValue statements order untouched.

Finally, while adding date fields (DueDate, ForMonth and DatePaid), use ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") so that Access will interpret the value as date. Also, parse the amount field to double.

Below is my version of the code. Hope this will work :)

```js
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = "UPDATE Bills SET Payer = @Payer, Category = @Category, Recipient = @Recipient, [Currency] = @Currency, Amount = @Amount, IBANOfRecipient = @IBANOfRecipient, Model = @Model, ReferenceNumber = @ReferenceNumber, Description = @Description, DueDate = @DueDate, ForMonth = @ForMonth, Paid = @Paid, DatePaid = @DatePaid WHERE Id = @Id";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payer", bill.Payer);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", bill.Category);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Recipient", bill.Recipient);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Currency", bill.Currency);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", Convert.ToDouble(bill.amount));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IBANOfRecipient", bill.IBANOfRecipient);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", bill.Model);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReferenceNumber", bill.ReferenceNumber);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", bill.Description);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DueDate", bill.DueDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ForMonth", bill.ForMonth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paid", bill.Paid);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatePaid", bill.DatePaid.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", bill.Id);

try
{
  return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch
{
  return -1;//for error
}
```

Comment: Through long chat long with Steve we came up with a solution to the problem and went step by step.. Currency was a problem, it needed brackets, and after that using `command.Parameters.Add("@Id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = bill.Id;` to specify format type for the database fixed issues with dates and everything else. but I do commend you for your work because it worked as well! :)